# I have two binary trees. I wanted to deep copy the result of the two binary trees without changing the input trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

```
class Node{
public:
friend class BinaryTreeAdd;
Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
}
 int getValue() const
{
    return value;
}

Node* getLC() const
{
    return left;
}

Node* getRC() const
{
    return right;
}
void setValue(int value) {
    this->value = value;
}
void setLC(Node* left) {
    this->left = left;
}
void setRC(Node* right) {
    this->right = right;
}
 public:
   int value;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
 };
class class BinaryTreeAdd {
 public:
static Node* cpNode(const Node* source)
{
    if (source == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return source == nullptr? nullptr
           : new Node(source->value,
            cpNode(source->left),
            cpNode(source->right));
}
 static Node* add(Node *t1, Node *t2){
    if (t1 == NULL) {
         return t2;
    }
    if (t2 == NULL) {
         return t1;
    } 
    t1->value += t2->value;
    t1->left=add(t1->left, t2->left);
    t1->right=add(t1->right, t2->right);
    return t1;
}
void display(Node * node){
    while (node != NULL) {
        cout << node->getValue() << endl;
            display(node->getLC());
            display(node->getRC());
        return;
    }
}
};
int main(){
BinaryTreeAdd bt;
Node root1(3, NULL, NULL);
Node root2(1, &root1, NULL);
Node root3(3, NULL, NULL);
Node root4(5, &root2, &root3);

Node root5(5, NULL, NULL);
Node root6(6, NULL, &root5);
Node root7(5, NULL, NULL);
Node root8(2, &root6, &root7);

Node *root9 = BinaryTreeAdd::add(&root4, &root8);
Node *root10 = BinaryTreeAdd::cpNode(root9);
bt.display(root10);
return 0;
}
```

1. I have merged two trees t1 and t2 and stored the results back in t1
   (add function).
   Function call: Node *root9 = BinaryTreeAdd::add(&root4, &root8);
2. Then I have deep copied the t1 to source (cpNode function).
   Function call: Node *root10 = BinaryTreeAdd::cpNode(root9);
3. I have used a display function to print the results of the deep copy.
   Function call: bt.display(root10);

My question is:

> 1. How should I copy the contents of t1 and t2 directly to the source node using cpNode function?
> 2. Contents of t1 and t2 should not be changed after merging the trees.

Comment: This is an extremely odd way to add binary trees. Are you sure you are doing something that makes sense?

Comment: Yes. I am sure.

Comment: I had this question in my interview. I wasn't able to solve it. So I need help to figure out this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function you need. It's recursive, like the input function. I simplified the logic a bit with the odd choice to permit recursion even if one node is NULL. This makes things easier because otherwise, I'd need separate code to duplicate the input node in that case.

```
// This function returns a newly-created
// node that merges the supplied input nodes
// per the requested algorithm.
// Either t1 or t2 or both can be NULL
static Node* add(Node *t1, Node *t2)
{

    // We don't want to create a new node if
    // both input nodes are NULL
    if (t1 == NULL) && (t2 == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return new Node (
          // The value is the sum of the input node
          // values or the input node value if just one
          (t1 ? t1->value : 0) + (t2 ? t2->value : 0),

          // The left node of the new node is the sum
          // of the input left nodes
          add (t1 ? t1->left : NULL, t2 ? t2->left : NULL),

          // The right node of the new node is the sum
          // of the input right nodes
          add (t1 ? t1->right : NULL, t2  ? t2->right : NULL));
}
```